# Hive TPCDS Query30 "Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed "

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, benchmarking

I am getting the above error when trying to run a tpcds query 30 in Hive. I did research and know this is not allowed in Hive so I am wondering how to rewrite this query. I directly got it from this website.
http://www.tpc.org/tpcds/default5.asp

`Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'ctr_state': Only SubQuery expressions that are top level conjuncts are allowed`

### Query 30

```
with customer_total_return as
 (select wr_returning_customer_sk as ctr_customer_sk
        ,ca_state as ctr_state, 
   sum(wr_return_amt) as ctr_total_return
 from web_returns
     ,date_dim
     ,customer_address
 where wr_returned_date_sk = d_date_sk 
   and d_year =2000
   and wr_returning_addr_sk = ca_address_sk 
 group by wr_returning_customer_sk
         ,ca_state)
  select  c_customer_id,c_salutation,c_first_name,c_last_name,c_preferred_cust_flag
       ,c_birth_day,c_birth_month,c_birth_year,c_birth_country,c_login,c_email_address
       ,c_last_review_date_sk,ctr_total_return
 from customer_total_return ctr1
     ,customer_address
     ,customer
 where ctr1.ctr_total_return > (select avg(ctr_total_return)*1.2
        from customer_total_return ctr2 
                      where ctr1.ctr_state = ctr2.ctr_state)
       and ca_address_sk = c_current_addr_sk
       and ca_state = 'GA'
       and ctr1.ctr_customer_sk = c_customer_sk
 order by c_customer_id,c_salutation,c_first_name,c_last_name,c_preferred_cust_flag
                  ,c_birth_day,c_birth_month,c_birth_year,c_birth_country,c_login,c_email_address
                  ,c_last_review_date_sk,ctr_total_return
limit 100;
```

### Update

Query 30 may have a typo when you generate the query using the tpcds suite. This does not exist in the customer table `c_last_review_date_sk` and you need to change it to `c_last_review_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate  `avg(ctr_total_return)` in the subquery `customer_total_return` using analytic function and remove subquery from the `WHERE`:

```
with customer_total_return as
(
select ctr_customer_sk, ctr_state, ctr_total_return,
       avg(ctr_total_return) over(partition by ctr_state ) as ctr_state_avg
from
 (select wr_returning_customer_sk as ctr_customer_sk
        ,ca_state as ctr_state, 
   sum(wr_return_amt) as ctr_total_return
 from web_returns
     ,date_dim
     ,customer_address
 where wr_returned_date_sk = d_date_sk 
   and d_year =2000
   and wr_returning_addr_sk = ca_address_sk 
 group by wr_returning_customer_sk
         ,ca_state
) s
)

  select  c_customer_id,c_salutation,c_first_name,c_last_name,c_preferred_cust_flag
       ,c_birth_day,c_birth_month,c_birth_year,c_birth_country,c_login,c_email_address
       ,c_last_review_date_sk,ctr_total_return
 from customer_total_return ctr1
     ,customer_address
     ,customer
 where ctr1.ctr_total_return > ctr1.ctr_state_avg*1.2
       and ca_address_sk = c_current_addr_sk
       and ca_state = 'GA'
       and ctr1.ctr_customer_sk = c_customer_sk
 order by c_customer_id,c_salutation,c_first_name,c_last_name,c_preferred_cust_flag
                  ,c_birth_day,c_birth_month,c_birth_year,c_birth_country,c_login,c_email_address
                  ,c_last_review_date_sk,ctr_total_return
limit 100;
```

Comment: Great thanks for the help! I noticed the tpcds query 30 itself has a typo when I ran it. c_last_review_date_sk should be c_last_review_date.